# What is the best way to declare a global variable?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In C++, say you want to declare a global  variable to be used by many. How do you do it?

I commonly use declare and define in cpp file, and then use extern  in other cpp file (and not headers).

I don't like this approach, and I am considering something along these lines:

In a header file:

some_file.h

```
Class MYGlobalClass
{

};


MyGlobalClass& MyGlobalClassInstance()
{
   static MYGlobalClass instance; 
   return  instance;

}
```

**Edit**

***Consider  in the following contexts:***

- can be used in multi-threaded applications
- namespace pollution
- may NOT necessery be a singleton, as many instances of this might be created

What are your thoughts, suggestions, new ideas?

Comment: Singleton design pattern

Comment: Not a good idea, look at comments below

Comment: A global variable, of which you want to create several instances? Looks like you still need to elaborate a bit...

Comment: say std::string class. you can use it through the code. and also have that instance as a global (and possibly mutable)

Comment: Daniel: Why? Even if it wasn't for the information edited in, a singleton wouldn't help. Singleton is not a replacement for globals, and it is not superior to globals.

Comment: Pukku: int i; int main() {int j; }
That program declares a global of type int, without limiting you to one instance of that type (main() declares a local instance as well)

Comment: @jalf: Ok, but wouldn't this work for any normal class? Looks like I'm completely missing the point here.

Comment: @Sasha: Why exactly is it that you don't like the usual extern way?

Comment: Well surely multi-threadedness is one aspect that you need to consider (already covered to some extent by Earwicker's answer), but anything else? If worried about namespace pollution, why not just put it in one?

Comment: "it" = both the class itself, and the MyGlobalClassInstance function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare it in one header file (using `extern`), and define it in *one* `.cpp` (or whatever other extension) file. You may use a function and return a reference to a static variable like you showed to circumvent problems with construction order relative to other such namespace scope variables in other `.cpp` files. But remember that won't protect you from destruction order problems - which is in the exact reverse order from construction (these things are called "static initialization order fiasco". If you use a function like yours and put it into headers, make it inline to make the redefinition of the function valid when it is included into multiple `.cpp` files (logically, the function is still only apparent once, because the static in it will only exist once, not separately for each file it is included into). Alternatively just declare it in a header but define it in *one* `.cpp` file (but then, remove the inline from it!).

```
inline A& getA() { static A a; return a; }
```

The potential problems with destruction order can be circumvented by using `new`:

```
inline A& getA() { static A *a = new A; return *a; }
```

The destructor of it, however, will never be called then. If you need thread safety, you should add a mutex that protects against multiple accesses. `boost.thread` probably has something for that.

Comment: what is the problems with destruction order?

Comment: it's the exact reverse order of construction. i.e if an object is created before you called getA() the first time, then it will be destroyed after the object in getA(). I.e there is a particular order. If you for example access getA() in the objects destructor, you will access a dangling reference.

Comment: search for "static initialization order fiasco" and i think you will find quite a few explanation (longer than my short overview here, of course) of that weirdness.

Comment: note that "constructed" means that the constructor finished. so if B does B() { getA(); } in its ctor then the A object in getA() is constructed *before* B (because its ctor finishes first), and you can safely do ~B() { getA(). .. } in B's destructor.

Comment: its too late to sleep, I will learn and post any further update here

Comment: Thanks Litb Following links is helpful in understanding the problem http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html

Answer (score 10):

The best advice is probably "try to avoid globals". People don't need global variables as often as they think. Usually it turns out that "passing everything as arguments to constructors" isn't quite as much work as people think when they hear the suggestion. It also tends to lead to cleaner code with fewer, and more explicit, dependencies.

I'm not aware of any "correct" way to declare globals in C++. The way you do it now works fine, but the order of initialization is unspecified, so if there are any dependencies between your globals, you're in trouble.

A function returning a static instance more or less solves that problem, but isn't thread safe.

And a singleton is just a terrible idea. It doesn't solve your problem, but adds additional constraints to your code, which weren't actually necessary, and will most likely come back and bite you later.

Answer (score 4):

Declare as extern in one header file included by "many" and define it in one *.cpp file

Comment: Good idea! perhaps define an inline function in header file? and include the header by many?

Comment: No school like the old school.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of a static inside the accessor function is significantly different from a global variable. The difference is when it is constructed, and is most likely to be a major problem with multiple threads. What if two threads call `MyGlobalClassInstance` at the same time? Depending on the environment, but I suspect this is typical of most C++ compilers, you will potentially get two calls to the constructor of `MyGlobalClass` running at the same time, addressing the same area of memory.

If you're single-threaded, it's less likely to be a problem.

If you declare the instance as a normal static member or as a normal global variable in the source file, you'll probably have an easier time, because the constructor will be called before `main` executes, before you have a chance to start other threads.

Comment: On the other hand, if you declare a plain global variable, you get all the problems with unpredictable initialization order.

Comment: Assuming that you don't need to be calling it all the time and therefore can afford the overhead, why not just add a scoped lock in the beginning of MyGlobalClassInstance ?

Comment: @Sasha: That was terrible. But I laughed anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> declare and define in cpp file

Keep the `extern`-ed declaration in a header. Define it *only once* in an implementation file.

You are close. Use a namespace instead for global variables.

```
namespace myns {
   int foo = 0;
}
```

Now, if it is a class object, you are looking at the Singletion pattern. In fact, your sample code reflects a Singleton design. However, if you are going to define the function in the header, make it inline -- ODR violation otherwise.

Comment: You are thinking of a Singleton object. In that case have an accessor and use it. Of course, you still need to include the header. Take a look.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: Thank you, I'm familiar with Singleton. However, it is NOT the solution I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It it's truly a global variable that could theoretically be accessed externally by any module, you should put the extern declaration in the header file:

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass { ... };
extern MyClass myGlobalInstance;

// MyClass.cpp
MyClass myGlobalInstance;
```

If it's just a global object that should really only be accessed by a single module, limit its scope by either making it a private (or protected) static class variable, a static function variable (if it's only needed by one function), or in an anonymous namespace:

Option 1:

```
// MyClass.h
class MyClass
{
private:  // or protected, if you want it accessible by subclasses
    static MyClass myGlobalInstance;
};
```

Option 2:

```
// MyClass.cpp
void someFunction()
{
    // it's global, but only accessible inside this function
    static MyClass myGlobalInstance;
    ...
}
```

Option 3:

```
// MyClass.cpp
namespace
{
    MyClass myGlobalInstance;
}

// it's now only accessible in this file
```

Answer (score 0):

extern MyGlobalClass MyGlobalClassInstance;

Edit: Not static >.<

Comment: static will not work, I need to share it accross files, modules, or even libraries. thanks for your time though

Answer (score -1):

Why not use good old singleton pattern?

Comment: Because it only adds new problems, and doesn't solve the one he needs solved

Comment: I don't want just one instance of that class! plus a needless overhead

Comment: But the code you have written is a singleton with exactly one static instance!!

Comment: No it isn't. There's nothing to stop Sasha from instantiating multiple MYGlobalClass instances. A singleton would make that impossible. A singleton *guarantees* that precisely one instance will exist.